I need to add the line of code below where I can add angular.UNSAFE_restoreLegacyJqLiteXHTMLReplacement()
I am using jQuery v3.5.0 and andularjs v1.8.3
I need to add the line of code below where I can add angular.UNSAFE_restoreLegacyJqLiteXHTMLReplacement();
auto close the open tag.
I refer the angular document: Migrating from 1.7 to 1.8 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-7-to-1-8

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
